# Links inside iframe opens inside app in Ionic2

Tags: cordova, iframe, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using Ionic2.
All "a" tags inside my iframe component opens up inside the app without any navigation controller or anything. Here is the setup for my iframe component `<iframe  style="display:block; height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow:hidden;margin:auto" src="//some link" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen seamless target="_top"></iframe>` 
This is the a link inside the iframe component:

`<a id="aw0" target="_blank" href="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click?xai=AKAOjst4Pf34OtdbZTzJANxCX99MNc4yKy75-46wYrTNB8dCtGR5qpNM0BVJ4u0Bjw_QJZWLCGxBouRB3nvH5QFcO0AI_zJY7fOrL5RM3tgB9QgsMgkFofy_QkIF1lS7KkJukSmwSDVvgLenDQc7BU7b4vcxKFbLDv9KQVcZJKU2at76WYwQjv0jbz9yKhjtNoq2E-p1WkZpFOGCqICwZQTbXRnMkwUE46dI2FJpUdjx&amp;sig=Cg0ArKJSzIA3h-k9ZNkF&amp;adurl=https://www.erkekvebakim.com/sakal-biyik-boyasi-11%3Futm_source%3Dtv8%26utm_campaign%3Dtv8-canli-yayin%26utm_medium%3Dpreroll""></a>`
How can i make this to open up in new browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the target option to system -
target="_system"

Comment: I have changed iframe's target but no luck, it doesn't work. And I can't manipulate "a" element's target option, it is out of my control.

Answer (score 0):

I've found one solution on Ionic forum. You can override the anchor tag's behaviour on iframe's onload property like this. `<iframe  onload="$(this).contents().find('a').on('click', function(e) {e.preventDefault(); var url = e.currentTarget.href; window.open(url, '_system', 'location=yes'); });"></iframe>`